# Expanding SPF macros

Tags: macros, expand, spf, abnf

I'm trying to implement a check_host function based on the SPF RFC7208. It is almost ready and the thing that has left is the macro expansion detailed in section 7 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-7). I know there are readily available solutions to this but for the sake of example or practice I want to implement my own algorithm. While doing so I have the problem that [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) does not fit the ABNF description. I assume it is because of my wrong reasoning and that is why I'm asking for help.

This is the ABNF copied from the document:

```
domain-spec      = macro-string domain-end
domain-end       = ( "." toplabel [ "." ] ) / macro-expand
toplabel         = ( *alphanum ALPHA *alphanum ) /
                  ( 1*alphanum "-" *( alphanum / "-" ) alphanum )
alphanum         = ALPHA / DIGIT
explain-string   = *( macro-string / SP )
macro-string     = *( macro-expand / macro-literal )
macro-expand     = ( "%{" macro-letter transformers *delimiter "}" )
                  / "%%" / "%_" / "%-"
macro-literal    = %x21-24 / %x26-7E
                  ; visible characters except "%"
macro-letter     = "s" / "l" / "o" / "d" / "i" / "p" / "h" /
                  "c" / "r" / "t" / "v"
transformers     = *DIGIT [ "r" ]
delimiter        = "." / "-" / "+" / "," / "/" / "_" / "="
```

I think that applying domain-spec to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) would follow this path: domain-spec -> macro-string -> macro-literal (repeated) and this will eat up the whole string and then domain-end will never match.

Where am I wrong?

Edit 1:

I think I got the answer and the original question becomes more like a request for a confirmation. The repetition in ABNF is greedy but probably allows for back off - i.e. eat less if this would lead to a match. Looking at RFC5234 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234), though not in its entirety, I was not able to definitely spot this. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Isn't it because `www.example.com` is not a macro, so there's nothing to expand?

Comment: I think that even then the grammer should by applied in order to validate the domain-spec section of the various mechanisms.